# Grimshaw in practical (OTB) game

Tags: problems, master-games

Does anybody know of an example of the **[Grimshaw-Theme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimshaw_(chess))** being used in a practical game?

For the Nowotny there are several examples (e.g. [Navara-Dergatschova, Ordix, 2007](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1470666)) and for the Plachutta there is [Tarrasch vs. Allies (Naples, 1914)](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1378821), but I can't find any practical example of a genuine Grimshaw.

Any ideas?

Comment: Somebody should compile a list (probably not on CSE) of problem motifs in OTB games. Encountered a few myself...

Comment: I am having issues locating any games , however that doesn't mean they aren't out there. The biggest issue you face is at very high level play where the bulk of databases focus on , its rare to see players play moves that result in a Grimshaw-Theme ... generally speaking

Comment: One idea might be to search for positions in which a Grimshaw was possible, at the very least.